# Why do I have so many Docker images with REPOSITORY name = <none>?

Tags: docker

When I type the command `docker images` to display the images I have the following:

```
REPOSITORY              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
rhel-httpd              latest              fbf8d1f684c2        17 hours ago        21.1MB
<none>                  <none>              8e78b0845d65        17 hours ago        21.1MB
<none>                  <none>              facd9f65febe        17 hours ago        21.1MB
<none>                  <none>              c0aa5de96c38        17 hours ago        21.1MB
express-mongo           latest              cbb3272e59e6        18 hours ago        21.1MB
<none>                  <none>              ad2d7dce3f31        18 hours ago        427MB
<none>                  <none>              a21766b25c6e        18 hours ago        1.08GB
express-mongo           latest              8a389964a9da        18 hours ago        933MB
react                   app                 0fdb29acba70        18 hours ago        1.08GB
api_web                 latest              2a36a4ae57a4        19 hours ago        933MB
<none>                  <none>              e36940791278        20 hours ago        1.03GB
<none>                  <none>              24bc73878199        20 hours ago        1.46GB
<none>                  <none>              a35acb3d26f3        20 hours ago        1.03GB
<none>                  <none>              78d1cc9c676a        21 hours ago        1.03GB
<none>                  <none>              b79a74a0663c        21 hours ago        1.46GB
<none>                  <none>              fd398d636305        21 hours ago        1.46GB
<none>                  <none>              459cc063b63c        21 hours ago        1.03GB
<none>                  <none>              cfa5dca23e0c        22 hours ago        1.03GB
<none>                  <none>              35f67b8276a0        23 hours ago        1.46GB
```

> Where do these come from?
>
> Should I be deleting them it looks like they are taking up significant size?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the intermediate layers(images) that you build using dockerfile. Inorder to save just the final layer, you can add rm intermediate images parameter

i.e `docker build --force-rm ...(other parameters)`  while building the docker image

Also `docker image prune` removes these intermediate images.

Comment: Very helpful thank you `Total reclaimed space: 5.718GB`